# X509Certificate2UI alternatives with .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I am currently porting a .NET application to .NET Core in order to run it on a Mac, this application gets some information about Digital Certificates, Type A3.

After running .NET Portability Analyzer, the only problem I got was regarding a call to **X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection**

Is there any way I could port this call to another one? Or any suggestions on how to do that automatically without the need of asking the user to choose the certificate from that dialog?

Comment: [MSDN documentation of `X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2ui.selectfromcollection)

Comment: Time to build your own UI elements, or check what native API macOS offers. You simply cannot keep using `X509Certificate2UI`. I met the same challenge to show the certificate, so I used https://github.com/jexuswebserver/JexusManager/blob/master/JexusManager.Shared/DialogHelper.cs#L35

Comment: You'll have to figure out some other form of prompting the user, such as printing summary information to Console.Out and reading back an index.